# How to identify an element in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button which appears as a web popup

On Inspect Element I have the following code .

```
<input type="button" id="#ICYes" name="#ICYes" class="PSPUSHBUTTONTBYES" value="Yes" 
onclick="javascript:oParentWin.submitAction_win0(oParentWin.document.win0, '#ICYes');
closeMsg(null,modId);" tabindex="0" alt="Yes" title="Yes">
```

```
driver.findElement(By.id("#ICYes")).click();
```

is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the hashtag from the id since the driver is already searching specifically for an id that is "ICYes".

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ICYes")).click();
```

Comment: Tried driver.findElement(By.id("ICYes")).click(); . Still it's not working

Comment: Try to copy the css path then use By.cssSelector('css selector')

Answer (score 0):

```
[python]
```

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ICYes'))).click()
or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ICYes').click()
```

api - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html